# How to fit box-shadow <li> element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I had `li` element that I make into two column, I want to add `box-shadow` on two column, but box-shadow do not fit the two-column I make, here is what I tried:

```css
.ul1 {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.li1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

.li1:nth-child(-n+5) {
  border-right: 0px;
}

.ul1 li:last-child,
.ul1 li:nth-child(5) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul1">
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
</ul>
```

I do not why this happen, I had try to set fix-height, but it doesnt work, 
I could use some guidance and suggestion to solve this

Comment: Remove your list left-padding: `.ul1 {padding-left: 0;}`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS:

```
.ul1 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to

```
    ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

and you don't need this class name like this , you can get style by tag name or some like this .

thanks